# Can i read private messages send to my bot in discord?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i have a discord.py bot and i used a command to send everyone in my server a private message but after i realised i didn't know if i can read the response. Is there a way to see the DM's send to my bot? Else i have to private message everyone myself since selfbots aren't allowed. The code used to send out private messages is displayed here:

```
@bot.command()
async def adm(ctx):
  await ctx.message.delete()
  for user in ctx.guild.members:
    try:
        message = (MY_MESSAGE)
        await user.send(message)
        print(f"Sent {user.name} a DM.")
    except:
        print(f"Couldn't DM {user.name}.")
  print("Sent all the server a DM.")
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can. you can create a bot control center server. And make stuff for every message your bot recieves in dm goes inside a channel of this server :)

Comment: Hi, can this be done after i received the messages? And do you have a link for me to a youtube vid or something how to do it? :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is not an answer, this should be a comment.